# Garage roof eaves missing closure strips

Tags: garage

So my garage roof is missing closer strips under the eaves, which I believe is letting some amount of moisture into the garage, as well as allowing tons of bugs and spiders to get in.

I would like to put some closure strips in under the eaves, but am unsure of how to go about this for an existing garage roof. I have read one recommendation that says to take the screws off the eaves of the garage roof, if possible, to fit closure strips under; which sounds like would be the best way to do it.

Hoping someone can give some advice on this. Attached are some pictures of the garage roof from the inside and outside.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to seal things up that tightly? It'll might be a lot warmer inside all of a sudden. Maybe just install screen.

Comment: @isherwood yeah that probably would have been a better idea (I ended up going with spray in foam). I think I will need to install some roof vents in there, it was already getting pretty warm in there on hot days. I live in the PNW though, so I don't think it will get hot enough to damage anything in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the exact size as your corrugated panels, removing the screws and inserting the strips would be the best way to do it and give you the best results. If you can't get the exact size, then you could cut them to fit or you could use Great Stuff expanding foam. Again, getting the right ones would be your best bet.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for more advice JACK :) Yeah seems like that would be the way to go. I found this site that was helpful in identifying the type of closure strips I would need: https://www.abcmetalroofing.com/Products/Components/Accessories/Commercial-and-Industrial/Closure-Strips. Getting the exact size could still be tricky I guess.

Comment: If you haven't started yet, @pauwlsky, you might want to only remove the screws from a panel or two at a time and not pull the whole thing at once. OTOH, if you're done and this worked for you, give it a check mark so others know that this has an accepted, workable answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @FreeMan, I ended up going with the spray in foam solution, because I couldn't find any closure strips that would fit the older style of garage roofing I have.

Comment: Write up your own answer, @pauwlsky that indicates this and give yourself the check mark. It'll help others know that there's a working solution.

Comment: @FreeMan  I think one of the answers say to use foam.

Comment: Yup, this one does - I missed that a minute ago... Give JACK a check mark for his efforts, then!